# PHP Chmod on Windows

Tags: php, chmod

I'm trying to do a simple `chmod` for a text file on Windows, later I want to differentiate which one is writable or not.

Now I have changed the `chmod` with 755, but it still says the same even after running the PHP script.

```
<?php
chmod('Math.txt',755); //tried 0755 still didn't work
echo "</br>";
echo substr(sprintf('%o', fileperms('Math.txt')), -4);
?>
```

Comment: Something similar, maybe: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/739891/php-mkdir-chmod-and-windows

Comment: @PraveenKumar that user's problem is creating it... but I'm trying to figure out how to change the permission...