# chmod is not working on windows 7

Tags: cmd, chmod

chmod is not working on windows 7

Comment: chmod is a unix command

Comment: I want to execute a php file from command line in windows.

Comment: You can have a look here http://php.net/manual/en/install.windows.commandline.php. I think what you need is run CMD as administrator

Comment: This has been discussed here .. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/739891/php-mkdir-chmod-and-windows

Answer (score 4):

`chmod` is a Unix command it will not work on Windows.  You need to use a windows equivalent such as [cacls](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/cacls.mspx?mfr=true) or [xcacls](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc781299%28v=ws.10%29.aspx).

Comment: How do I do this in windows chmod +x build.sh?

Comment: but not limited to that, chmod can still run on Windows if you install Git on your windows machine. I've tried and it's working.

Answer (score 0):

Try using Icacls for Windows 7 . chmod is for unix as Kevin already said .. PHP chmod doesn't work in windows 7

Comment: What would be the equivalent in lcacls of chmod 600?